# Using Facebook Graph API In Flash AS3 To Post To Photo Album

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api, for-loop

i am facing 1 problem here i uploaded "Using Facebook Graph API In Flash AS3 To Post To Photo Album" example on my server with my app ID but when i am trying to login it cant login and dont show my name please help me what i do…?

**here is the example post**
http://permadi.com/blog/2011/02/using-facebook-graph-api-in-flash-as3-to-post-to-photo-album/comment-page-1/#comment-1782

**here is the example URL**
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/as3-save-photo-to-facebook-album/?test

and the example URL working fine  :(

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear which is perhaps why it's been downvoted.

The facebook APIs are a constantly moving target a lot of the older Flash frameworks that integrate with Facebook use old deprecated APIs.

I've found this framework to be very clean and clear and works with Facebooks more recent APIs - https://github.com/Dareville/Facebook-Graph

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The given links also tells you why the example does not work since it was compiled with APIs 1.5 and Facebook APIs has updated and changed.

My recommendation is downloading the latest version 1.8.1 and following instruction on the links above.

Some changes that you must following from upgrading to 1.8.1

Change response.session to response.authResponse.
Change getSession in .js to getAuthResponse.
perms is now called scope.

"redirect" is useless now, so just removing from loginHandle

```
function handleLogin(response:Object, fail:Object):void {
if (response == null)  {
//resultTxt.text += 'Error login session';
ExternalInterface.call('redirect'); // useless <-- remove it
return;
}
changeToLoginState();
}
```

One more important thing that I saw many people asking loginHandler does not invoke when authentication complete. Almost the reason is that your SWF object has hot given the id or name. REMEMBER to give the name and id via SWFObject lib. See my example below, focusing on the bold text.

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {allowScriptAccess: "always",wmode: "transparent"};
**var attributes = {id:"main",name:"main" };**
swfobject.embedSWF("main.swf","flashContent", "810", "525", "11.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",flashvars, params, attributes);
```